# Download File using web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to download a file using web API 2. But the browser gives "the web page is not available" when I directly give the url in the browser.

I have written following Custom Action

```
 public class FileActionResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public FileActionResult(string data)
        {
            this.Data = data;
        }

        public string Data { get; private set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string tempFolderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/api/tempfiles");
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            string folderPath = Path.Combine(tempFolderPath, guid.ToString());
            if(!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
            }
            string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, guid.ToString() + ".json");
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, Data);
            string zipFile = folderPath + ".zip";
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folderPath, zipFile);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(zipFile));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "file.zip",
                DispositionType = "attachment"
            };
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
```

I am not sure what is wrong here. Can somebody help me in this?

**Edit**
When I use Google-PostMan to check the methods it shows proper response. How to force the browser to download the file?
Thanks

Comment: This code looks good to me. May be something wrong in your WebAPI method? Are you sure you use a proper HTTP verb there?

Comment: I mean "page is not available" could lead wrong method call, i.e. your method expects GET but you use POST, or wrong number of method params, or custom routing issues. Try to catch your call using F12 browser tools and analyze input params and server response.

Comment: I am to debug the method by hitting the url

Answer (score 1):

The code is working fine. However the issue was related to Telerik Control. I am using Telerik controls on my website. Telerik was doing some compression while file download. 
I had to bypass my url to make it work.

```
    <sectionGroup name="telerik.web.ui">
      <section name="radCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompressionConfigurationSection, Telerik.Web.UI" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <telerik.web.ui>
    <radCompression>
      <excludeHandlers>
        <add handlerPath="some path" matchExact="false"/>
      </excludeHandlers>
    </radCompression>
  </telerik.web.ui>
```